# Redirect page and tacking on .html extension

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

In my conf file,i want to rewrite all my URLs from a subdomain (blog.domain.com) to the root domain, removing the trailing slash (if available) and appending the ".html" extension.

```
blog.domain.com/my-first-link/  -->  www.domain.com/my-first-link.html
```

But i dont want the ".html" extension to be added for the root of the subdomain

```
blog.domain.com/                -->  www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Put this in the blog subdomain `VirtualHost`. If you don't have a blog `VirtualHost` it should work in the main host config as well.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: is it specific to blog.domain.com? i have other rewrite conditions and rules in my conf file

Comment: @gdup: I didn't notice you were changing hostnames...This should now take care of it (including catching SSL properly). If you're not using SSL feel free to remove that part.

Comment: for some reason, subdomain url "blog.example.com" is not redirecting to "www.example.com"

Comment: @gdup: can you post your apache config into a pastebin somewhere that I can look at?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BAmeqfM9

Comment: Unknown paste ID. You'll need a longer expiration time.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WdfTx8ge

Comment: @gdup: Ok, I updated it and tested it based on your comments. I removed the SSL part (since you're not using it) and added a rule to catch the bare hostname.

Comment: @gdup: Not a problem, glad I could help.